# Read python variables from a file

Tags: python, metadata

I would like to read all variables stored in a file like this :

```
var1=val1
var2=val2
..etc
```

Is there a way to access to a metadata where I can find and list all variables without knowing their names?
In my script I am using `execfile("myFile.txt")`.

Comment: What is wrong with making a module and adding your variables as a constants ?

Comment: I don't have access to write to that file, and because it is used by others, it should stay like that.

Comment: Can you *read* this file? Or do you want to write Python code that knows all defined variables?

Comment: have a look at the [configparser](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/configparser.html#module-ConfigParser) module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`execfile` actually supports what you want to do.

```
global_vars = {}
local_vars = {}

execfile("myFile.txt", global_vars, local_vars)

# local_vars now contains the variables defined in the file.
print local_vars
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval() to set the variables or you can turn the file to a dictionary, I think the second solution is more safe than the first one ! You can also make a class and use setattr(self, name, value) to attach the variables to that class dynamically and using the parsed strings.